# SQL Query Format Datetime?

Tags: sql, datetime, format

I've seen a lot of posts on this, but can't seem to find the format I am looking for.  I have multiple dateime fields in a SQL view I am building.  It looks like this: `2016-02-16 00:00:00.000`

I want it to look like this:

```
02/16/2016 12:00:00 PM
```

I've been looking at `Convert(varchar, datetimefield, 1)`
and changing out the 1 for other numbers.

Does anyone know which number I need, or if I should use a different method to get the exact format I want?

I also want any NULLs to be blank, so it will be helpful to figure how to best wrapper the solution in an `ISNULL(x,'')` unless the solution needs to be worked in a way that will allow an isnull.

Thank you

Thank you

Comment: When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I don't think you are going to get "12PM" for midnight using *any* built-in formatting function.  My advice is to get used to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.  It is ANSI standard, ISO standard, unambiguous, and sorts correctly.

Comment: Those date-time values are different; the current way you are seeing it is   midnight, and the one you want it like is noon

Comment: are you converting it to string or datetime

Comment: Sorry, yes, that would be AM.  It is naturally a datetime datatype. I just want it to be formatted nice in the view.

Comment: What is the presentation layer for this?

Comment: I'm not sure why the "presentation layer" matters, but I'm making this into a view, and it will be linked into Excel, so the users have a simple excel report of whats in the db.

Comment: Then let Excel do the formatting.

Comment: I can't. Every time the connection is refreshed, it will revert.

Comment: "Presentation Layer" is what the end user will be viewing; in this case Excel.
Excel has it's own Date-Time formatting, so leave it alone.
Excel can also deal with the NULL values.

Comment: @MadMyche is right...another reason you don't want to format in the view is that you want excel to know its a date data type, not a string, which will be useful for filtering and sorting.  If it thinks its a string, it will use a whole different set of filtering/sorting that will be incorrect.

Comment: OK, I can do that.  But what do I do about NULLs?  I want those to be blank.

Comment: I like the layout of this page, it has a good list of the conversion values and their corresponding formats:  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp --- I would not try to handle nulls at the db level in your scenario, instead handle them in your presentation layer.  I use an Html Helper function to often replace nulls with "---" or the like so my ui fields are not just empty.

Comment: You're overthinking this a little.  Break it into 3 pieces.  1. Retrieve data from db.  2.  Display to your view.  3.  Write to excel.  You can actually skip formatting it on retrieval all together.  Format it with string format before sending it to your view, then utilize the raw data you retrieved when writing to excel.  Otherwise you're going to be doing multiple manipulations to the data that are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you all.  I am trying to leave it alone.  I'll see if the formatting in Excel keeps through refreshing the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  convert(varchar(20),getdate(),101) 
+ ' ' +
right(convert(varchar(32),getdate(),108),8) AS Date_Time -- this gives you military time but you can replace it with this which gives you AM/PM
right(convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 100) ,8) --AM/PM
```